# Fetch URI from Post Data through Get Data

Tags: json, angular, postdata

Show 1 textfield with 2 buttons - Post, Get. Take a number as input in a text  field.  On clicking Post, create an array of the numbers from 1 to that number. Post this array at the URL. Display the response from the Post.On clicking Get, fetch data from the URL returned by the Post and display it.

```
urlPost = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins';
clist: number[] = [];
strData: string = '';
S1: String = '';
ntext: number;
constructor(private netService: NetService) {}

postData() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= this.ntext; i++) {
        this.clist.push(i);
    }
    this.netService.postData(this.urlPost, this.clist)
        .subscribe(postresp => {
            this.strData = JSON.stringify(postresp);
        });
}

getData() {
    this.netService.getData(this.strData.Uri)
        .subscribe(resp => {
            this.strData = JSON.stringify(resp);
        });
}
```

this line need to be improved.

```
this.netService.getData(this.strData.Uri)
```

Comment: make your `postData()` return an observable & subscribe to it in your `getData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand your question, you simply have a problem with parsing a response from your `postData()`. So, just refer to the following -

```
postData() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= this.ntext; i++) {
        this.clist.push(i);
    }
    this.netService.postData(this.urlPost, this.clist)
        .subscribe(postresp => {
            this.S1 = postresp['uri'];    // get URL here
        });
}

getData() {
    this.netService.getData(this.S1)      // use it here
        .subscribe(resp => {
            this.strData = JSON.stringify(resp);
        });
}
```

See it working ***[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3c4fup)***.

Comment: cant it be done by storing the result into a string and then fetching value from that string in getdata()

Comment: it can be, if you are always going to call it using a button with some delay between both buttons.

Comment: by this i am not getting the desired ans. As by clicling Get button it should display the elements of array list created in Postdata()

Comment: i am just getting an another link by pressing get button.

Comment: can you please forward me that string option code. As per now i havent covered the subscribe and observable topic in this.

Comment: what will be your response from `postData()`? show a sample object

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw1f8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  see this

Comment: input any number and press Post Data and then open the URL which is dipslay as an output..the output which is shown by that link i want that to be our output after clicking the Get button